Google Maps API v3 Algorithm (MarkerClusterer) not working
I initialize map and via ajax function (filters) I want to change numbers of markers (clusters) and star markers loads on map. I tried dynamically initialize markerClusterer in async function because I use advanced Markers (AdvancedMarkerElelement) to load access to this class from "marker" library, but I got not built clusters in t.MarkerClusterer object (clusters returns null). I am using @googlemaps/markerclusterer the unpkg version.
var map;
var markers_field = [];
var markerCluster;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {lat: parseFloat('52.373920'), lng: parseFloat('9.735603') },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            keyboardShortcuts: false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    gestureHandling: "greedy",
    streetViewControl: false,
    heading: 0,
    tilt: 0,
    mapId: "55f47556969d555c",
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    setPolygon(map,coord_c,69);

    readFilters();
}

async function loadMarkerLibrary() {
try {
    const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
    // Use AdvancedMarkerElement or perform other operations here
    console.log("Marker library loaded successfully");
    return AdvancedMarkerElement; // Return if needed
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error loading marker library:", error);
    // Handle error appropriately
    }
}

async function setMarkers(map, includes, c) {

        const markerElement = await loadMarkerLibrary();

        markers_field.forEach(marker => marker.setMap(null));
        markers_field = [];

        var i_color= 'red';
        let j_counter = 1;
        for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

            const point = points[i];
            if(c=='cat')
                i_color = colors_c[point['cat_id']];
            if(c=='item')
                i_color = colors_i[point['item_id']];
            if(c=='dtls')
                i_color = colors_d[point['dtls_id']];
            if(c=='sub_dtls')
                i_color = colors_sd[point['sub_dtls_id']];
            if(c=='subcat')
                i_color = colors_sc[point['subcat']];
            if(c=='subcat2')
                i_color = colors_sc2[point['subcat2']];

            if (inArray(point['id'], includes) && point['i_x']!==''&&point['i_y']!=='' ) {

                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.className = 'custom-marker';
                div.innerHTML = point['contentStringImage']+'<div class="marker-point"></div><div class="marker-text text-white">'+point['contentStringTitle']+'</div>';

                icon_image = div;

                let shouldDisplayMarker = true;

                // Display marker if it should be shown
                if(shouldDisplayMarker) {

                    markers_field[j_counter] = new markerElement({
                        position: {lat: parseFloat(point['i_x'] - delta), lng: parseFloat(point['i_y'])},
                        //map,
                        content: icon_image,
                        //icon: icon2,
                        zIndex: (j_counter + 1),
                        //gmpDraggable: true
                    });


                    infowindow[j_counter] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: point['contentString'],
                        ariaLabel: "",
                    });


                    markers_field[j_counter].customData = j_counter;

                    google.maps.event.addListener(markers_field[j_counter], 'click', function (evt) {

                        var j_counter_tmp = this.customData;

                        if (currentInfoWin !== null) {
                            currentInfoWin.close(map, this);
                        }

                        infowindow[j_counter_tmp].open({
                            anchor: markers_field[j_counter_tmp],
                            map,
                            shouldFocus: false,
                        });

                        currentInfoWin = infowindow[j_counter_tmp];

                    });

                    j_counter++;

                }
            }
        }

       
        if(markerCluster)
        {
            // Clear previous markers from the MarkerClusterer
            markerCluster.clearMarkers();
        }

        // Initialize and configure MarkerClusterer with custom algorithm
        const customAlgorithm = {
            calculate: ({ markers, map }) => {

                if (!markers || markers.length === 0) {
                    console.warn('No markers provided to customAlgorithm.calculate');
                    return [];
                }

                var clusters = [];

                markers.forEach(marker => {
                    if (marker && marker.position ) {

                        let addedToCluster = false;

                        for (let cluster of clusters) {
                            const distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(marker.position, cluster.center);
                            if (distance < 20) { // Example distance threshold for clustering
                                cluster.markers.push(marker);
                                addedToCluster = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!addedToCluster) {
                            clusters.push({center: marker.position, markers: [marker]});
                        }
                    }
                });

                console.log(clusters);

                const result =  clusters.map(cluster => ({
                    position: cluster.center,
                    markers: cluster.markers,
                    count: cluster.markers.length,
                }));

                console.log('Custom Algorithm Result:', result);
                return result;
            }
        };

      
        const filteredMarkers = markers_field.filter(marker => marker !== undefined);
        console.log('Filtered Markers:', filteredMarkers);

        // Initialize MarkerClusterer with custom algorithm and small gridSize
        markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({
            map: map,
            markers: filteredMarkers,
            gridSize: 30, // Small grid size for fine clustering
            algorithm: customAlgorithm, // Use custom clustering algorithm
            maxZoom: 20, // Max zoom level for clustering
            minimumClusterSize: 2 // Minimum cluster size for clustering
        });

        console.log(markerCluster);

        markerCluster.addMarkers(filteredMarkers);

        var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
        handleZoomChange(currentZoom);

        // Listen for zoom changes
        map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
            var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
            handleZoomChange(currentZoom);
        });
    }

    function handleZoomChange(zoomLevel) {
    if (zoomLevel > 15) {
        markerCluster.setMap(null); // Disable clustering
        showIndividualMarkers();
    } else {
        markerCluster.setMap(map); // Enable clustering
        hideIndividualMarkers();
    }
}

function showIndividualMarkers() {
    markers_field.forEach(marker => {
        marker.map = map;
    });
}

function hideIndividualMarkers() {
    markers_field.forEach(marker => {
        marker.map = null;
    });
}

function readFilters()
{
        cat_id = jQuery('#cat_id').val();
        item_id = jQuery('#item_id').val();
        dtls_id = jQuery('#dtls_id').val();
        sub_dtls_id = jQuery('#sub_dtls_id').val();
        subcat = jQuery('#subcat_id').val();
        subcat2 = jQuery('#subcat2_id').val();
        year_from = jQuery('#year_from').val();
        year_to = jQuery('#year_to').val();

        var show_to_archeologist = 0;

        area_id = jQuery('#area_id').val();
        area_id_all = jQuery("#area_id_all").val();

        area_id_all = area_id_all.split(",");
        for(let i=0;i<area_id_all.length;i++)
            hidePolygon(area_id_all[i]);

        for(let i=0;i<area_id.length;i++)
            setPolygon(map,coord_c,area_id[i]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/m/gmap_cluster.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {"cat_id": cat_id, "task":"filters", "id":69, "area_id":jQuery("#area_id").val(), "item_id":item_id, "dtls_id":dtls_id, "sub_dtls_id":sub_dtls_id, "subcat":subcat, "subcat2":subcat2, "year_from":year_from, "year_to":year_to, "show_to_archeologist":show_to_archeologist},
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (result) {

                if(result!='' && jQuery("#inlineCheckbox01").is(":checked") )
                {
                   
                    includes = result.split(",");

                    c = 'all';
                    if(!isEmpty(cat_id) && isNotNullArray(cat_id) )
                        c = 'cat';
                    if(!isEmpty(item_id) && isNotNullArray(item_id))
                        c = 'item';
                    if(!isEmpty(dtls_id) && isNotNullArray(dtls_id) )
                        c = 'dtls';
                    if(!isEmpty(sub_dtls_id) && isNotNullArray(sub_dtls_id))
                        c = 'sub_dtls';
                    if(!isEmpty(subcat) && isNotNullArray(subcat))
                        c = 'subcat';
                    if(!isEmpty(subcat2) && isNotNullArray(subcat2))
                        c = 'subcat2';

                    setMarkers(map, includes, c);

                }
                else {
                    for(let i=0;i<markers_field.length;i++) {
                        if(isSet(markers_field[i])) {
                            markers_field[i].setMap(null);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

markerCluster console result: t.MarkerClusterer {markers: Array(19), clusters: Array(0), algorithm: {…}, renderer: B, onClusterClick: ƒ, …}...

Custom Algorithm Result: (8) \[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}\]
0: {position: \_.zr, markers: Array(3), count: 3}
1: {position: \_.zr, markers: Array(5), count: 5}
2: {position: \_.zr, markers: Array(4), count: 4}
3: {position: \_.zr, markers: Array(3), count: 3}
4: {position: \_.zr, markers: Array(1), count: 1}
5: {position: \_.zr, markers: Array(1), count: 1}
6: {position: \_.zr, markers: Array(1), count: 1}
7: {position: \_.zr, markers: Array(1), count: 1}
...

error in chrome console:
Uncaught TypeError: r is not iterable
at t.MarkerClusterer.render (markerclusterer.ts:187:31)
at t.MarkerClusterer.onAdd (markerclusterer.ts:233:10)
at Hqa.draw (overlay.js:4:860)
at Iqa.vi (overlay.js:4:1116)
at Apa (map.js:54:428)
at map.js:54:1


Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, with all the required HTML/CSS and some sample data, preferably a StackSnippet in the question itself

This is my simplified code. Please note that you need to replace YOUR_API_KEY in the code with your actual Google API key:


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places,drawing,geometry,marker"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclusterer/dist/index.min.js"></script>
<script>
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var infowindow = [];
var currentInfoWin = null;
var markerCluster;

async function loadMarkerLibrary()
{
  try {
      const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
      // Use AdvancedMarkerElement or perform other operations here
      console.log("Marker library loaded successfully");
      return AdvancedMarkerElement; // Return if needed
   } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error loading marker library:", error);
      // Handle error appropriately
   }
}

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887 },
    zoom: 4,
    keyboardShortcuts: false,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    gestureHandling: "greedy",
    streetViewControl: false,
    heading: 0,
    tilt: 0,
    mapId: "90f87356969d889c",
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
});

// Listen for zoom changes
map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
    const currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    handleZoomChange(currentZoom);
});

readFilters(1);

handleZoomChange(map.getZoom());

function handleZoomChange(zoomLevel) {
    if (zoomLevel > 15) {
        markerCluster.setMap(null); // Disable clustering
        showIndividualMarkers();
    } else {
        markerCluster.setMap(map); // Enable clustering
        hideIndividualMarkers();
    }
}

function showIndividualMarkers() {
    markersArray.forEach(marker => {
        marker.setMap(map);
    });
}

function hideIndividualMarkers() {
    markersArray.forEach(marker => {
        marker.setMap(null);
    });
}
}

function getRandomFloat(min, max) {
return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

async function readFilters(filter_group)
{
const markerElement = await loadMarkerLibrary();

markersArray.forEach(marker => marker.setMap(null));
markersArray = [];

if(filter_group==1)
    var max_points = 100;
if(filter_group==2)
    var max_points = 50;
if(filter_group==3)
    var max_points = 25;

// Create an array of markers (example data)
for (let i = 0; i < max_points; i++) {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'custom-marker';
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png">'+'<div class="marker-point"></div><div class="marker-text text-white">marker '+(i+1)+'</div>';

    const marker = new markerElement({
        position: {
            lat: -28.024 + (getRandomFloat(0.96,1) - 0.95) * 0.1,
            lng: 140.887 + (getRandomFloat(0.96,1) - 0.95) * 0.1
        },
        content: div
    });
    markersArray.push(marker);
}

// Initialize and configure MarkerClusterer with custom algorithm
const customAlgorithm = {
    calculate: ({ markers, map }) => {

        if (!markers || markers.length === 0) {
            console.warn('No markers provided to customAlgorithm.calculate');
            return [];
        }

        var clusters = [];

        markers.forEach(marker => {
            if (marker && marker.position ) {

                let addedToCluster = false;

                for (let cluster of clusters) {
                    const distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(marker.position, cluster.center);
                    if (distance < 100) { // Example distance threshold for clustering
                        cluster.markers.push(marker);
                        addedToCluster = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!addedToCluster) {
                    clusters.push({center: marker.position, markers: [marker]});
                }
            }
        });

        console.log(clusters);

        const result =  clusters.map(cluster => ({
            position: cluster.center,
            markers: cluster.markers,
            count: cluster.markers.length,
        }));

        console.log('Custom Algorithm Result:', result);
        return result;
    }
};

// Initialize MarkerClusterer with custom algorithm and small gridSize
markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({
    map: map,
    markers: markersArray,
    gridSize: 30, // Small grid size for fine clustering
    algorithm: customAlgorithm, // Use custom clustering algorithm
    maxZoom: 20, // Max zoom level for clustering
    minimumClusterSize: 2 // Minimum cluster size for clustering
});

console.log(markerCluster);

markerCluster.addMarkers(markersArray);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

</script>
    
#map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
}
.custom-marker {
    width: 40px;
    height: 60px; /* Adjust height as needed */
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-marker img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
}
.custom-marker .marker-point {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px; /* Position below the image */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.custom-marker .marker-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px; /* Position below the point */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
}
<select name="filter" onchange="readFilters(this.value)">
    <option value="1">Group Points 1</option>
    <option value="2">Group Points 2</option>
    <option value="3">Group Points 3</option>
</select>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="map"></div>




Thanks all. Problem is solved. I created custom algorithm class and use in markerclusterer. code class CustomAlgorithm {
calculate({ markers, map }) {...})}code
